# Wrong data when reading with sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I am using R and sparklyr process some data from Spark. I am reading two parquet files, in sequence, with

```
v1 <- spark_read_parquet(sc, "events","s3n://project/sessions.parquet", memory="true")
head(v1)
v2 <- spark_read_parquet(sc, "events","s3n://project/users.parquet", memory="true")
head(v1)
head(v2)
```

After the first read, head gives, correctly, the info that is in the table just read. After the second read, head(v1) gives the info that is in *second* table, not the first. Data is always correct in v2. Any hints?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can reproduce this. I have some doubts about your memory parameter thought. I believe it should be `memory=True` or `memory=T` and not `"true"`. There should be no brackets there.

Comment: you are right, but it works this way too.